# batch file programming

Tags: file, batch-file

I tried to copy one file to another from starting line upto a limit. ie.,
line 1 to 10(file1.txt)->file2.txt
but while writing "!" is skipped. what can i do for to solve it. Any help will be thankful.

The loop for that function is given below.

```
%NF%-> new file.

%EF%-> existing file

%1% -> line number(passed from another part)

:_doit

findstr /N /R "." %EF%|findstr /B /C:"%1:">nul

if errorlevel 1 (    
    echo. >>%NF%        
) else (    
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('findstr /N /R "." %EF%^|findstr /B /C:"%1:"') do (    
        if [%%a] EQU [] (    
            echo. >>%NF%    
        ) else (    
            echo %%a >>%NF%    
       )     
   )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if errorlevel 1 ( 
    echo. >>%NF% 
) else ( 
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('findstr /N /R "." %EF%^|findstr /B /C:"%1:"') do ( 
       if [%%a] EQU [] ( 
          echo. >>%NF% 
       ) else( 
          setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion 
          echo %%a >>%NF%
          endlocal
       ) 
    )
)
```

Comment: There are two problems, "echo." is two times slower as "echo(" and it fails if a file named "echo" exist. The second problem is with long files your code doesn't work, because you didn't use endlocal and therefore you get an overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you can download tools, you can use [GNU win32 gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

```
gawk.exe "NR>10{exit}1"  file1 > file2
```

And you can take a look at this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805036/read-only-x-lines-from-a-txt-file-with-a-windows-batch-file/3809913#3809913) that is similar

Comment: yes, its just a command. So put that command inside your batch file.

Comment: Do you know what the reason for disappearing "!" symbol in batch file while writing from one file to another?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the delayed expansion, if you disable it, also the ! work as expected.
You can disable it only for the loop.

```
if errorlevel 1 (    
    echo. >>%NF%        
) else (
   setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('findstr /N /R "." %EF%^|findstr /B /C:"%1:"') do (    
        if [%%a] EQU [] (    
            echo. >>%NF%    
        ) else (    
            echo %%a >>%NF%    
       )     
   )
   endlocal
)
```

The parser for batch lines has multiple phases:
The first phase is the %var% expansion, then comes the special character phase "^<>&|()
and after the %%a phase, the delayed (exclamation phase).

That's the reason why the ! dissappear in your case.
Because you got something like this from your file
%%a=Hello!
Then the exclamation phase try to expand the !, but this fails and it is removed.

If in your file is the line
Hello^!
you got in your "copy" 
Hello!

But in a batch file you need two carets to display one !

```
echo hello^^!
```

Because in phase2, the ^^! is inflated to ^!, and in the exclamation phase the last caret escapes the !

Comment: But i placed the DisableDelayedExpansion in next else block to work properly.Thanks.

Comment: if errorlevel 1 (

  echo. >>%NF% 

) else (

   for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('findstr /N /R "." %EF%^|findstr /B /C:"%1:"') do ( 

  if [%%a] EQU [] (
 
   echo. >>%NF%

   ) else( 

   setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

   echo %%a >>%NF% 

   endlocal 
  )

  )

 )

Comment: Note that `for /f` will skip empty lines.

Comment: Yes, but there can't be empty lines, because findstr /N always prepend the line number

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use gawk.exe from [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download) :

```
gawk "NR<10" < file1 > file2
```

Comment: Better GNU gawk : gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm