# Read ONLY x lines from a txt file with a windows batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

How can I read only X lines from a a.txt file?

The file contains all the names of a directory, I would like to read only x lines.
X can be a number that can varies from 1 to 99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to modify this based on your needs, but the script below will loop through the file 'directories.txt', and ECHO the contents of the line until you hit the maximum number of lines set in `maxlines`.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET /A maxlines=1
SET /A linecount=0

FOR /F %%A IN (directories.txt) DO ( 
  IF !linecount! GEQ %maxlines% GOTO ExitLoop
  ECHO %%A 
  SET /A linecount+=1
)

:ExitLoop

PAUSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think is what I needed, I just have to try it

Comment: The linecount is not incremented. It remains at the initial value

Comment: Works for me in XP; what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows server 2003

Comment: If I write in the dos command set /a linecount+=1 is incremented, but it is not from inside the batch file :((

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste in what you have so far?  This works on Windows Server 2003 R2 also, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: What I have writte is this: @echo off setlocal enabledelayedexpansion dir /b /o:-d /t:c "D:\backup e ckpdb EPT-ICD\test\unload\*.rar" > "D:\backup e ckpdb EPT-ICD\test\unload\lista_files_rar.txt" set /a maxlines = 5 set /a linecount = 1 for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("D:\backup e ckpdb EPT-ICD\test\unload\lista_files_rar.txt") do ( if %linecount% GEQ %maxlines% goto exitloop echo %%a %linecount% %maxlines% set /a linecount+ =1 ) :exitloop pause

Comment: Batch files are very unforgiving.  I see a few things wrong.  1.  You should have `SET /A linecount=1` without spaces before or after the equal sign.  2.  I had `!linecount!`, while you have `%linecount%`.  3.  I had `set /a linecount+=1`, you have a space between the plus sign and the equal sign.  I strongly suggest you copy my example *as is*, and make sure it works before you modify it.

Comment: Side note: `for /f` will skip empty lines in the file so this will not work if they can appear in the files.

Answer (score -1):

you can use vbscript. Here's an example

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strNum = objArgs(0)
strFile=objArgs(1)
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfLine
    If CInt(objFile.Line) > CInt(strNum) Then
      Exit Do  
    End If 
    strLine=objFile.ReadLine
    WScript.Echo strLine    
Loop
```

save as myscript.vbs and

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo myscript.vbs 99 file
```

Or if have the luxury to install tools,
you can download [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) or  [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) for windows . Then on the command line

```
sed.exe "99q" file
gawk.exe "NR>2{exit}1" file
```